# I want my already logged in users to have my ViewController3 as rootViewController and those who aren't logged in to have ViewController2

Tags: swift, authentication, rootviewcontroller

Does somebody know which code I should add to my project? The problem I also have is that I use pre-built log in VC, so I am unsure if I can use the same code as those who have built one themselves

Comment: Hi @Fellep it would be good if you can post your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logged Users -> ViewController3
Not Logged Users -> ViewController2

**Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5UkS4Mrepo at [24:38]**

You need to store a value in default user (Core Data / inside the device Phone).
Based on this value feed or not you can redirect users proprely :

Add this to your AppDelegate.swift :

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) 
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Onboarding")
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "LoginComplete") {
        initialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3")
    }
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Add this code to your login Viewcontroller3

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "LoginComplete")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Remove the arrow (initial ViewController) from the mainstoryboard if any 
This assume that you ViewController2 is the initial VC

Comment: Which func should I put the first lines of code into the AppDelegate.swift? @A.HEDDAR

Comment: The rootViewController just turns out to be black now. I want to have an intro view controller  (Viewcontroller2) with the app name but that doesn't come up now. @A.HEDDAR

Comment: Please see the updated code the function is  : func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

Comment: Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5UkS4Mrepo at [24:38]